# AKS create failed

Tags: azure-container-service

I'm trying to use azure container service but when I run

```
az aks create --resource-group DockerEEcluster --name myK8sCluster --node-count 1 --generate-ssh-keys
```

I get the following error

> Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 9ccd3cf6-02f2-4147-9333-c50ba948e248. Timeout while polling for control plane provisioning status

The resource group location is West Europe.
Any help?